# what exactly are ports?

Tags: io, port, microprocessors

Generally I/O ports in microprocessor refer to a certain memory address in the RAM that a microprocessor is listening to (correct me if I am wrong).

Does "port" mean the same way when we talk about TCP/IP port, FTP port etc., ?

I am not sure if the question is properly phrased. If it is not properly, it may be due to my understanding of ports being not precise.

Answer (score 2):

In this case (from what I think you mean) a port is just an interface between the physical pin and the register that stores those values. There will be hardware that samples these pins and places the values into a register for use in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Basically. As stated by wikipedia:

> Hardware port: a physical interface between a computer and other computers or devices
>
> Software port: a virtual data connection between computer programs possibly through a computer network

So you can think of them as both being bridges between one intelligence and another (be it a program or hardware).

Also, both are the transfer of data as bits from one register - or location in memory - to another.

For most purposes, they are the same.